# ¿Debería la RAE intervenir activamente en la lengua?

Tags: modismos, rae, extranjerismos

*Desconozco si preguntas de debate abierto son bienvenidas aquí, si fuera el caso estaría bien una etiqueta `debate` u `opinión`*

¿Opináis que la RAE (y similares academias lingüísticas) deben tener un rol activo en la evolución de la lengua, o ser meros observadores?

Por un lado tenemos que se tiene que intentar preservar la lengua, evitar una completa invasión de modismos ya que la perdida de identidad no sólo afecta a la lengua sino a la cultura entera.

Por otro lado no se puede forzar a una lengua a ser de una forma, y la institución correspondiente debe adaptarse a cómo la gente habla y no a la inversa.

¿Cuál es vuestra opinión en este tema? ¿Debería la RAE intervenir en la lengua? ¿En qué medida?

Comment: Nótese que en [se] es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, no un foro. Por tanto, las preguntas deben ser algo tangible que pueda contestarse más o menos objetivamente. Es por ello que iría bien que modificaras el redactado para que vaya más con este espíritu.

Comment: No sé si podría ser una pregunta adecuada para [Spanish Language Meta](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/). Allí sí hay etiquetas para debates, pero las preguntas deben ir acerca del sitio en sí (de ahí lo de _meta_), así que no sé si encajaría. Es una lástima porque podría ser un debate interesante. ¿La RAE no tiene una opinión propia al respecto?

Comment: Cierro pues esta pregunta como _primarily opinion-based_ a la espera de actualizaciones.

Comment: @fedorqui, estoy de aqcuerdo, no creo que una reformulacion a pregunta cerrada sea adecuada ya que la naturaleza de la pregunta era para tener debate al respeto. Si bien entiendo que es un sitio de Q&A, creo que los debates en ciertos aspectos le darian vida asi como un mayor sentimiento de comunidad

Comment: Precisamente estuvimos (¿estamos?) debatiendo al respecto en [¡Estamos de enhorabuena! Estado efervescente del sitio y cómo seguir creciendo](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2490/1674). ¡Te invito a participar!

Comment: @fedorqui ¿se podría usar una sala de chat para los debates? Al menos así es como se orienta en el sitio StackOverflow en español. Para la naturaleza de este sitio, me parece que podrían haber dos salas de chat, una donde el idioma principal sea inglés y otra donde sea español.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ya existe [Spanish Language Meta](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=spanish.stackexchange.com), pero nunca hay nadie en él, igual que hay bastante poco debate en [meta]. Dado que el sitio tiene un volumen bastante bajo de preguntas, no sé hasta qué punto puede ser útil. Ahora bien, me parece una muy buena idea tenerlo en cuenta -e incluso anunciarlo en Meta- para poder comentar de una forma más dinámica las dudas que van surgiendo y dejar los comentarios para las preguntas en sí.

Answer (score 6):

La RAE, de hecho, toma un papel activo en la defensa de la lengua. Además de sus recomendaciones de uso, en ocasiones se desmarca con campañas a favor del uso del castellano y en contra del exceso de invasiones externas. Una muestra de ello es su reciente campaña en contra del abuso de términos ingleses en el mundo del *marketing* (¿o mercadotecnia?) y la publicidad. Podéis ver el vídeo (lanzado el 18 de mayo de 2016) en YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBEomboXmTw

Os recomiendo su visionado, porque está hecho con mucho sentido del humor.

Así pues, respondiendo a tu pregunta, la RAE sí que debe (y de hecho lo hace) intervenir en la lengua. ¿En qué medida? Pues ejemplos como el vídeo lo dejan claro: cuando hay un peligro flagrante de corrupción del idioma, considerándose como *corrupción* una desviación anómala en un intervalo de tiempo demasiado breve. Todo lo que no sea eso se consideraría como una simple evolución del mismo.

Comment: Si el [preguntador(1)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TzdcIRq) reformula la pregunta a "¿Interviene la RAE activamente en la defensa de la lengua?", podría quedar como respuesta. Muy bueno el vídeo.

Comment: Este vídeo merece un monumento.