# ¿"Win-win" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Es común oír la expresión **win-win** para referirse a una situación en la que todas las partes involucradas salen beneficiadas:

> - Tengo unas entradas para el concierto de Juan Luis Guerra pero no puedo ir. Qué rabia. Con lo caras que me costaron, ahora qué hago con ellas.
>   - ¡Yo te las compro! A mí me encantaría ir y así tú no pierdes tu dinero.
>   - Caramba, menudo win-win.

<sub>(Lo mismo me salió un poco forzado el ejemplo)</sub>

Bueno, pues este concepto ha arraigado con fuerza, hasta el punto que últimamente lo oigo bastante en conversaciones e incluso en análisis políticos.

¿Sabéis de alguna traducción válida del concepto? [Ganar-ganar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juego_ganar_ganar) es lo más directo, pero me parece algo rupestre.

Comment: Aquí se usa mucho. "Ese negocio es un gana-gana para todos"

Comment: Aquí en Perú también utilizamos Ganar-ganar para esta expresión. Inclusive lo he escuchado en discursos políticos transmitidos por la televisión. Quizás sea porque no se conoce otra idea similar en español por lo que se usa la traducción directa, que dicho sea de paso se entiende por sí solo.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza es interesante que menciones _ganar-ganar_ (el verbo), mientras que DGaleano dijo _gana-gana_ (el nombre). Y sí, definitivamente se entiende solo, pero no sé porqué nos ha dado a nosotros por decir _win-win_.

Comment: Supongo que hay personas que les gustan los anglicismos. Me has hecho recordar a [este comercial de la RAE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBEomboXmTw) (es off topic, luego lo elimino de comentarios).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza sí :)) Hace poco [Carlos Alejo lo mencionó](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17331/1674). Es fantástico. Anímate a contestar, hombre, que eres un miembro muy activo en [so] y [es.so] y aquí te explayas poco :)

Comment: @fedorqui le estoy agarrando la onda a este sitio poco a poco. Por lo pronto estoy revisando cómo otros usuarios responden para que mis publicaciones apoyen con la misma efectividad :)

Comment: En algunos casos se podría usar la expresión "y todos contentos".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esa idea de que en una situación, en vez de que las ganancias de una de las partes se produzcan a expensas de las pérdidas de la otra (como suele ser habitual), son ambas partes las que salen beneficiadas, podría expresarse como «**beneficio mutuo**» o «**ganancia mutua**» en castellano.

A falta (aparente) de una traducción «oficial», la primera expresión arroja unos 400.000 resultados en Google. La segunda le va muy a la zaga con unos 7000.